# How to parse a single-column text file into a table using python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm new here to StackOverflow, but I have found a LOT of answers on this site. I'm also a programming newbie, so i figured i'd join and finally become part of this community - starting with a question about a problem that's been plaguing me for hours.

I login to a website and scrape a big body of text within the b tag to be converted into a proper table. The layout of the resulting Output.txt looks like this:

```
BIN                   STATUS                                                   
8FHA9D8H 82HG9F     RECEIVED SUCCESSFULLY AWAITING STOCKING PROCESS          


INVENTORY CODE:   FPBC   *SOUP CANS LENTILS                                 

BIN                   STATUS                                                   
HA8DHW2H HD0138     RECEIVED SUCCESSFULLY AWAITING STOCKING PROCESS          
8SHDNADU 00A123     #2956- INVALID STOCK COUPON CODE (MISSING).          
93827548 096DBR     RECEIVED SUCCESSFULLY AWAITING STOCKING PROCESS
```

There are a bunch of pages with the exact same blocks, but i need them to be combined into an ACTUAL table that looks like this:

```
      BIN               INV CODE                          STATUS                                                   
HA8DHW2HHD0138     FPBC-*SOUP CANS LENTILS    RECEIVED SUCCESSFULLY AWAITING STOCKING PROCESS          
8SHDNADU00A123     FPBC-*SOUP CANS LENTILS    #2956- INVALID STOCK COUPON CODE (MISSING).          
93827548096DBR     FPBC-*SOUP CANS LENTILS    RECEIVED SUCCESSFULLY AWAITING STOCKING PROCESS          
8FHA9D8H82HG9F   SSXR-98-20LM NM CORN CREAM  RECEIVED SUCCESSFULLY AWAITING STOCKING PROCESS
```

Essentially, all separate text blocks in this example would become part of this table, with the inv code repeating with its Bin values. I would post my attempts at parsing this data(have tried Pandas/bs/openpyxl/csv writer), but ill admit they are a little embarrassing, as i cannot find any information on this specific problem. Is there any benevolent soul out there that can help me out? :)

(Also, i am using Python 2.7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple custom parser like the following should do the trick.

```
from __future__ import print_function



def parse_body(s):
    line_sep = '\n'
    getting_bins = False
    inv_code = ''
    for l in s.split(line_sep):
        if l.startswith('INVENTORY CODE:') and not getting_bins:
            inv_data = l.split()
            inv_code = inv_data[2] + '-' + ' '.join(inv_data[3:])
        elif l.startswith('INVENTORY CODE:') and getting_bins:
            print("unexpected inventory code while reading bins:", l)
        elif l.startswith('BIN') and l.endswith('MESSAGE'):
            getting_bins = True
        elif getting_bins == True and l:
            bin_data = l.split()
            # need to add exception handling here to make sure:
            # 1) we have an inv_code
            # 2) bin_data is at least 3 items big (assuming two for
            #    bin_id and at least one for message)
            # 3) maybe some constraint checking to ensure that we have
            #    a valid instance of an inventory code and bin id
            bin_id = ''.join(bin_data[0:2])
            message = ' '.join(bin_data[2:])
            # we now have a bin, an inv_code, and a message to add to our table
            print(bin_id.ljust(20), inv_code.ljust(30), message, sep='\t')
        elif getting_bins == True and not l:
            # done getting bins for current inventory code
            getting_bins = False
            inv_code = ''
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. Sorry it took so long to comment, had a loooong day at work. Everything looks perfect for what i'm looking for, but for some reason the console is returning "None". I've parsed some parts of Output.txt with a similar method, but i can't figure out what i'm doing wrong with yours. Is there some detail i'm missing? (using python 2.x)

Comment: The code should have generated a syntax error in 2.7 at the print() statement since the code uses the Python 3 print() function. Add `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of the module containing `parse_body()` and the code will run in both 2.x and 3.x. I updated the code accordingly.

Comment: I also added exception handling for the unlikely event that an inventory code is encountered when we are reading bins. Without the exception invalid data may be added to your table in this case.

Comment: oh nice catch! ill test it right now and see what happens

Comment: Ok so the bin and the message columns go together perfectly :), the only issue its having now is that the first inventory code repeated on every line going through, with the error code you wrote popping up for each of the rest of the inventory codes.

Comment: My reading of the OP is that the data follows a repeated pattern of <inv_code><blank_lines><bin_header><bins><blank_lines>. If there is no blank line separating bins from the next inv_code then the error you describe is expected. If the "blank" lines contain whitespace, then adding `l.strip()` as the first line in the `for` block should do the trick. Essentially, a custom parser like this requires identification of reliable patterns in the data. If the OP data examples are not complete, then only you can look at enough data sufficient to identify the necessary patterns.

Comment: There are always 2 blank lines between the last bin and the next inv code, and there is always one blank line between the code and the next bin_header. The pattern in the original post pretty much is the exact one it follows for the whole doc. I believe the blank lines do have about half a line worth of whitespace each, but when i add l.strip() under for, it just returns every inventory code as an error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120870/discussion-between-craig-burgler-and-patrick-o).

Answer (score 0):

A rather complex one, but this might get you started:

```
import re, pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

rx = re.compile(r'''
                (?:INVENTORY\  CODE:)\s*
                (?P<inv>.+\S)
                [\s\S]+?
                ^BIN.+[\n\r]
                (?P<bin_msg>(?:(?!^\ ).+[\n\r])+)
                ''', re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)

string = your_string_here

# set up the dataframe
df = DataFrame(columns = ['BIN', 'INV', 'MESSAGE'])

for match in rx.finditer(string):
    inv = match.group('inv')
    bin_msg_raw = match.group('bin_msg').split("\n")

    rxbinmsg = re.compile(r'^(?P<bin>(?:(?!\ {2}).)+)\s+(?P<message>.+\S)\s*$', re.MULTILINE)
    for item in bin_msg_raw:
        for m in rxbinmsg.finditer(item):
            # append it to the dataframe
            df.loc[len(df.index)] = [m.group('bin'), inv, m.group('message')]

print(df)
```

#### Explanation

It looks for `INVENTORY CODE` and sets up the groups (`inv` and `bin_msg`) for further processing in `afterwork()` (note: it would be easier if you had only one line of bin/msg as you need to split the group here afterwards).
Afterwards, it splits the `bin` and `msg` part and appends all to the `df` object.

Comment: Nice! Definitely more complicated, but i like that it makes a list of dictionaries. How would i go about converting those lists via DataFrame into the example table i posted? The part that's tripping me up is that there are lists as entries in the table. Also, how would i get the inv code to repeat per bin like the example table? thanks :)

Answer (score -2):

I had a code written for a website scrapping which may help you. 
Basically what you need to do is write click on the web page go to html and try to find the tag for the table you are looking for and using the module (i am using beautiful soup) extract the information. I am creating a json as I need to store it into mongodb you can create table.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import sys
import requests
import re
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import pymongo

def req_and_parsing():
        url2 = 'http://businfo.dimts.in/businfo/Bus_info/EtaByRoute.aspx?ID='

        list1 = ['534UP','534DOWN']
        for Route  in list1:
                final_url = url2 + Route
                #r = requests.get(final_url)
                #parsing_file(r.text,Route)

        outdict = []
        outdict = [parsing_file( requests.get(url2+Route).text,Route)  for Route in list1 ]
        print outdict
        conn = f_connection()
        for i in range(len(outdict)):
                insert_records(conn,outdict[i])


def parsing_file(txt,Route):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(txt)
        table = soup.findAll("table",{"id" : "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView2"})
        #trtags = table[0].findAll('tr')

        tdlist = []
        trtddict = {}
        """
        for trtag in trtags:
                print 'print trtag- ' ,  trtag.text
                tdtags =  trtag.findAll('td')
                for tdtag in tdtags:
                        print tdtag.text
        """

        divtags = soup.findAll("span",{"id":"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ErrorLabel"})

        for divtag in divtags:
        for divtag in divtags:
                print "div tag - " , divtag.text
                if  divtag.text ==  "Currently no bus is running on this route" or "This is not a cluster (orange bus) route":
                        print "Page not displayed Errored with below meeeage for Route-", Route," , " , divtag.text
                        sys.exit()

        trtags = table[0].findAll('tr')
        for trtag in trtags:
                tdtags =  trtag.findAll('td')
                if len(tdtags) == 2:
                        trtddict[tdtags[0].text] = sub_colon(tdtags[1].text)
        return trtddict


def sub_colon(tag_str):
        return re.sub(';',',',tag_str)

def f_connection():
        try:
                conn=pymongo.MongoClient()
                print "Connected successfully!!!"
        except pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure, e:
                print "Could not connect to MongoDB: %s" % e
        return conn

def insert_records(conn,stop_dict):
        db = conn.test
        print db.collection_names()
        mycoll = db.stopsETA
        mycoll.insert(stop_dict)

if __name__ == "__main__":
        req_and_parsing()
```

Comment: hey! thanks for taking the time to answer : ). i should have mentioned in my post that this entire body of text is inside the same tag (<b>). I have to parse it after i've already scraped it, but i'm not quite sure how to manipulate my text file to get that end table result.